# Can Google maps functions be loaded without loading the map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a site where I'm using Maps Javascript API to print several polygons to the screen and manage hover/click events, but I don't need to see the underlying map. At the moment I've just styled all of the map elements to white, and it works, but I'd rather eliminate the requests, since it's currently downloading ~40 seperate blank white squares.

Happy to try a different plugin / API if it works, but I had a look for alternate applications without much luck.

Comment: It's like asking for a pizza without cheeze... But I see a `GET` resquest that *may* be blocked. I said *may*... : `https://khms0.googleapis.com/kh?[query]`. But I can't tell how to block it. I saw it on the network tab.

Comment: Why do you use Map JavaScript API if you don't use map? If you use google maps just to draw some polygons - use special library for drawing like http://kineticjs.com/ or https://d3js.org/

Comment: Firstly, the polygons have been created by tracing regions on a Google map, and would be difficult to replicate otherwise. Concrete/KineticJS may be appropriate replacements.
Secondly, the Google maps API is something I'm fairly familiar with, so I went with personal ease, rather than learning a new API.